# How to define a number

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-science, metaphysics, philosophy-of-mathematics, terminology

What is the positive real number (say less than one) that is not a rational nor an irrational number?

I have encountered  a mathematical problem  that confused me about the definition of real numbers, so I thought there may be some other set of numbers that is not well defined !

Comment: This question may have metaphysical implications, but they are not apparent. Please, consider editing the question to reflect those concerns, or remove the tag.

Comment: I don't know why my answer is not visible normally, please note that math-exchang is not taking the question into consideration, so can you help in this regard the way you or somebody else finds it suitable?

Comment: See [Irrational number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number) : "In mathematics, an *irrational number* is any real number that cannot be expressed as a ratio of integers." Thus, the *real* numbers are made of two "disjoint" subsets : that containing the rationals and its complement including the irrationals. No way out from this : irrational are defined as those that are **not** rational.

Comment: Philosophy.SE is not configured to accept MathJax, so you'll have to go without it. Additionally, keep in mind that your question will be treated here for its philosophical content only.

Comment: The math site is dealing with this appropriately, despite what the questioner imagines, he would get no better reading here.

Comment: If there are only two kinds of Real numbers, that still gives you three categories of solutions in those terms: rational, irrational and **nonexistent**.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1435312/are-there-real-numbers-that-are-neither-rational-nor-irrational?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Wasn't the above-provided reference question the same as my question? wonder!

Answer (score -5, accepted):

If $x$ is positive rational number less than $\frac{1}{2}$,  can the following logarithmic expression be equivalent to any real number , say $r$?

$$\frac{\log(1-x)}{\log x} = r$$, Where $r$ is positive real number less than one,

Assume first $r$  is a rational number say $n/m$, then you would get this equation, $x^n=(1-x)^m$, where solution for $x$ will be clearly algebraic - irrational number contradicting the assumption of rationality of $x$, hence $r$ cannot be rational number & must be irrational number, if so, you get this following equation, $x^r = 1-x$, the right hand side is a rational number, but the left hand side is transcendental number according to - Gel-schneider theorem, that contradicts again the assumption of irrationality  of  $r$, so what is that number suppose to be?

I guess someone will simply say it is a transcential number given by definition, if so assume  $x$ an integer power of a rational number, say $x=a^p$, where  $p$ is odd prime number, then by substitution you get this simple equation which is a reduced form of FLT for rational numbers    ,  $a^p + (a^r)^p = 1$, but we already know that  $a^r = b$, where $b$ is a rational number that  doesn't exist from the proof of Andrew Wiles & Taylor to Fermat's Last Theorem, thus  $log(b) / log(a)$ is not Transcendental number, it is a kind of numbers that have to be redefined again & precisely

Comment: You may kindly view it clearly here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1311922/if-x-is-rational-can-log1-x-log-x-be-algebraic

Comment: Your question was well accepted there. The jury is still out on your answer, so if your patient enough, maybe what they have to say will satisfy your curiosity. As I said, it can only be of interest to us here for its philosophical content, i.e. as a matter of conceptual clarification.

Comment: Is it, that by FLT you mean Fermat's Last Theorem, and you think the above might be a short sweet proof? Then just think about it: he would surely have found place to write that in the margin. It's too short! :)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/644688/solve-equation-expax-expbx-1/1314639#1314639

Comment: No No, I gave up thinking of short proofs, thought may be shorter than you imagine, please read this with comments before they delete for the tenth times                                                             http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/644688/solve-equation-expax-expbx-1/1314639#1314639

Comment: If the answer you're looking for is purely mathematical, why is this question here on Philo.SE?

Comment: So you have answered the question by process of elimination r is neither rational nor irrational, and so it does not exist.

Comment: Actually, I didn't know this mathematical question would be too difficult for philosophers, because indeed it was too difficult even for the mathematicians, also I'm who is asking the question, and , ironically suggesting answers just to encourage or drag others to inter this debate, the whole question is to test the validity of our assumed assumption under a presence & a pressure of more complicated situations, where, our simple concepts or beliefs runs out of answers & collapse because it's limit had been reached , where simply a new thing must arise and replace it for the better and good.

Comment: @bassam karzeddin in math, our assumptions are called axioms. If you were to prove that our assumptions are invalid in "complicated situations", you'd have proven that the system we work in is inconsistent. I doubt you proved the inconsistency of ZFC with your simple example (not to say you'd provided a better system!). *You* should draw the conclusion and see where your reasoning fails. Many gave you some hints, just listen to them!

Comment: I think you're misusing Gelfond-Schneider theorem. It says a^r is irrational if a is rational and r is irrational *and algebraic* but r doesn't have to be algebraic in your case. Otherwise there would be trivial counterexamples to Gelfond-Schneider theorem.

Comment: My question was simply asking if new types of numbers could exist in addition to our known numbers, to outline that shortly, I can claim that, if   $n^r=m$, where ($n & m)$ are coprime integers greater than one & $r$ is real number that is not in our known numbers

Comment: r is an irrational, transcendal number. Its type is perfectly known. Having a number that is neither rational nor irrational would prove the inconsistency of ZFC.

Comment: This is the statement of the theorem: If a and b are algebraic numbers with a ≠ 0,1 and b irrational, then any value of a^b is a transcendental number. I really don't know who is misusing the theorem?

Comment: You only proved that r is not algebraic.

Comment: I also proved that r is not transcendental number, but a real number that is not defined in Mathematics yet, otherwise a  counterexample to Fermat's Last Theorem must be there, but, because it was proved beyond  doubt by Sir Andrew Wiles & Taylor in 1995, then r doesn't belong to our number system despite of it's existence

Comment: You cannot use FLT because a is not an integer (nor a^r).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24616/discussion-between-bassam-karzeddin-and-quen-tin).

Answer (score 4):

I'll give you the standard, schematic answer, but be aware that this question opens a Pandora's box.

Irrational numbers are those that cannot be indicated by a fraction of two integers. Because it is a negative definition, it can be a bit misleading, and unhelpful. See, all numbers that are not rational have to be... irrational.

There is, however, an "outer circle", a set of numbers that aren't rational, but that can be positively defined as those that are the solution of some algebraic equation. These are called the **algebraic** numbers.

The next circle outside is the set of **computable** numbers. These are, roughly speaking, the numbers that can be approximated to an arbitrary precision by a finite calculation process.

Numbers that are not algebraic are called **transcendental**. Most of these numbers are also not computable. Another negative definition, as you can see. There are (and probably will always be) more things that we do *not* know about these numbers than things that we do know, so if you are perplexed by them, you are in good company.

Comment: Can I exclude the transcendental numbers, since all real positive  transcendental numbers that are less than one are also irrational numbers that I have already excluded?

Comment: If you exclude the irrationals, all that you are left with are the rationals. Simple logic here.

Comment: I shall give an argument that may break this simple logic here!

Comment: Go ahead! It will be interesting.

Comment: If math breaks logic, we're doomed...

Comment: Logic almost broke maths.

Comment: http://www.quora.com/Can-we-find-two-positive-integers-n-and-m-such-that-n-pi-m                                                                                                                  Same issues may have much more attention somewhere else, you might like to look at more different philosophies of some others for the same content issue that seems bouring here for obvious reasons, so you can clearly see how philosphers or mathematikers  seems too tiny facing the hidden facts behind the properties of numbers, also I shall not call this as a discovery but a sychology of the common mathns.